# C++ Multithreading with boost::mutex within a child window

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, mutex

I am developing an application for Windows. I have written a class for drawing purposes, that will be accessed by several threads. The class is threadsafe by using mutex locks.

The good thing is, thread safety does not seem to be an issue, however, I seem to never get a lock when processing the WM_SIZE message (though I do get locks when processing other messages) and I do not understand why.

The class looks like this:

```
class DrawChildWindow {
    typedef boost::mutex::scoped_lock     scoped_lock;
    typedef boost::mutex::scoped_try_lock scoped_try_lock;
    typedef std::map<HWND, HDC>           WindowMap;
public:
    DrawChildWindow(HWND hWndParent);
    ~DrawChildWindow();

    // Will move the child window and repaint it
    void move(int x, int y, unsigned int cx, unsigned int cy);

    // Returns the HDC stored in the WindowMap
    HDC beginPaint();
    // Displays the edited HDC on the client area of the child window
    void endPaint();
private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

    boost::mutex        m_mutexLocal;         // for work with member variables
    static boost::mutex s_mutexGlobal;        // for work with static variables

    static WindowMap    s_map;                // Manages the created child windows
    HWND                m_hWnd;               // Handle of the child window
};
```

I've shortened it to show only the methods and members that, in my opinion, might cause the trouble. This is the respective implementation:

```
DrawChildWindow::DrawChildWindow(HWND hWndParent) {
    // I've cut the once-only registration of the window class here
    scoped_lock lockG(s_mutexGlobal);
    scoped_lock lockL(s_mutexLocal);

    m_hWnd = CreateWindow(L"DrawChildWindow", NULL,
        WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        m_hWndParent, NULL, __DCW_HINST, NULL);
    s_map[m_hWnd] = NULL;
}

DrawChildWindow::~DrawChildWindow() {
    scoped_lock lockG(s_mutexGlobal);
    scoped_lock lockL(s_mutexLocal);

    WindowMap::iterator it = s_map.find(m_hWnd);
    if(it != s_map.end())
        s_map.erase(it);
    DestroyWindow();
}

void DrawChildWindow::move(int x, int y, unsigned int cx, unsigned int cy) {
    scoped_lock lockL(s_mutexLocal);

    MoveWindow(m_hWnd, x, y, cx, cy, TRUE);
}

HDC DrawChildWindow::beginPaint() {
    scoped_lock lockG(s_mutexGlobal);
    scoped_lock lockL(s_mutexLocal);

    WindowMap::iterator it = s_map.find(m_hWnd);
    if(it != s_map.end()) {
        if(!it->second) {
            // I create a compatible DC here
            // and fit it to match the client area size
        }
        // I clear the background of the DC here
        return it->second;
    }
    // This should never happen
    return NULL;
}

void DrawChildWindow::endPaint() {
    scoped_lock lockG(s_mutexGlobal);
    scoped_lock_lockL(m_mutexLocal);

    WindowMap::iterator it = s_map.find(m_hWnd);
    if(it != s_map.end()) {
        if(it->second) {
            // I BitBlt the HDC into the client area here
        }
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DrawChildWindow::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(uiMessage) {
    case WM_SIZE:
        {   // This is the problematic block
            scoped_try_lock lockG(s_mutexGlobal);
            // This is never true
            if(lockG.try_lock()) {
                WindowMap::iterator it = s_map.find(hWnd);
                if(it != s_map.end() && it->second) {
                    DeleteDC(it->second);
                    it->second = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            scoped_lock lockG(s_mutexGlobal);
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            WindowMap::iterator it = s_map.find(hWnd);
            if(it != s_map.end() && it->second) {
                // I BitBlt it->second to hDC here
            }
            else {
                // Draw a notification that no data is available
            }
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uiMessage, wParam, lParam);
}

boost::mutex               DrawChildWindow::s_mutexGlobal;
DrawChildWindow::WindowMap DrawChildWindow::s_map         = WindowMap();
```

I am aware of the fact that `WM_SIZE` will be called while `CreateWindow()` - so it will be called in my constructor, where `s_mutexGlobal` is indeed locked. This is why I implemented it as a `scoped_try_lock`.

When the parent window's size is changed, I call `move()` to adjust the child window sizes, and they will be adjusted correctly, but the `HDC` of `s_map` will never be destroyed, and I fail to understand why I cannot lock `s_mutexGlobal` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using

```
if(s_mutexGlobal.tryLock()) {
    WindowMap::iterator it = s_map.find(hWnd);
    if(it != s_map.end() && it->second) {
        DeleteDC(it->second);
        it->second = NULL;
    }
    s_mutexGlobal.unlock();
}
```

instead of the `scoped_try_lock`. I discovered this while experimenting, and would still appreciate if someone had an explanation for this behavior.